# Hibernate: how to map collection of Double?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can I map a list of Double values

```
class Person {

    @Id
    private String key;

   @OneToMany
   @Column(name="values")
   private List<Double> values;
```

I get this error

```
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: Person.values[java.lang.Double]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the annotation `@CollectionOfElements` like:

```
@CollectionOfElements
   @Column(name="values")
   private List<Double> values;
```

This will work if you are using 3.4.

And if you're using Hibernate Annotations 3.5+, prefer the JPA 2.0 annotations use `@ElementCollection` annotation :

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name="values")
   private List<Double> values;
```

Comment: I use @CollectionOfElements and get error "Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: person, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(values)]"

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: hibernate-annotations\3.4.0.GA\hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar

Comment: You are using field access strategy (determined by @Id annotation). Put any JPA related annotation right above each field instead of getter property

Comment: i put the annotations mentioned by you on the fields and not on the getters